# LiveView plugin template creates lots of errors?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile, sony

I'm trying to get the LiveView plugin template to work but upon import of the project into Eclipse, I already have 13 errors and 2 warnings. I have already downloaded SDK for Android 1.6 which I believe is what it requires. The errors are as follows:

```
The method startPlugin() of type AbstractPluginService.LiveViewCallback must override a superclass method   AbstractPluginService.java  /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview/plugins    line 173    Java Problem
The method stopPlugin() of type AbstractPluginService.LiveViewCallback must override a superclass method    AbstractPluginService.java  /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview/plugins    line 182    Java Problem
The method onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences, String) of type new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(){} must override a superclass method    AbstractPluginService.java  /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview/plugins    line 360    Java Problem
The method onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName) of type new ServiceConnection(){} must override a superclass method AbstractPluginService.java  /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview/plugins    line 345    Java Problem
The method onServiceConnected(ComponentName, IBinder) of type new ServiceConnection(){} must override a superclass method   AbstractPluginService.java  /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview/plugins    line 318    Java Problem
The method screenMode(int) of type AbstractPluginService.LiveViewCallback must override a superclass method AbstractPluginService.java  /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview/plugins    line 230    Java Problem
The method openInPhone(String) of type AbstractPluginService.LiveViewCallback must override a superclass method AbstractPluginService.java  /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview/plugins    line 221    Java Problem
The method run() of type SandboxPluginService.Rotator must override a superclass method SandboxPluginService.java   /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview/plugins/sandbox    line 254    Java Problem
The method onUnregistered() of type AbstractPluginService.LiveViewCallback must override a superclass method    AbstractPluginService.java  /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview/plugins    line 216    Java Problem
The method run() of type SandboxPluginService.Timer must override a superclass method   SandboxPluginService.java   /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview/plugins/sandbox    line 235    Java Problem
The method displayCaps(int, int) of type AbstractPluginService.LiveViewCallback must override a superclass method   AbstractPluginService.java  /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview/plugins    line 206    Java Problem
The method button(String, boolean, boolean) of type AbstractPluginService.LiveViewCallback must override a superclass method    AbstractPluginService.java  /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview/plugins    line 196    Java Problem
The method getPluginName() of type AbstractPluginService.LiveViewCallback must override a superclass method AbstractPluginService.java  /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview/plugins    line 191    Java Problem
```

and the warnings:

```
The method getInterfaceDescriptor() from the type IPluginServiceV1.Stub.Proxy is never used locally IPluginServiceV1.java   /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/gen/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview    line 242    Java Problem
The method getInterfaceDescriptor() from the type IPluginServiceCallbackV1.Stub.Proxy is never used locally IPluginServiceCallbackV1.java   /com.sonyericsson.extras.liveview.plugins.PluginPreferences/gen/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveview    line 130    Java Problem
```

These all occur fresh from the ZIP file from Sony Mobile's Developer World. No code has been changed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need Java 1.6, not Android 1.6.

Java 1.6 should take care of the `override` issues.

Comment: I may be overlooking the obvious places but I can't seem to locate Java 1.6 from the java website. Can you also add a link to your answer? I don't know if the results have to do with Google customizing my "searching experience". Earliest I can find is Java SE 6.